# Do cloned streams from MediaStreamDestination are still somehow bound to this AudioNode?

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I'm having multiple WebRTC connections which I create on load so I need to have multiple input stream to handle them.

Actually, I created one single MediaStreamDestinationNode as followed and acquired streams for WebRTC connections as clones of stream from this node.

```
    microphoneNode = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
        var micNodeSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        micNodeSource.connect(microphoneNode);
    });

    var stream1= microphoneNode.stream.clone();
    var stream2 = microphoneNode.stream.clone();
    var stream3 = microphoneNode.stream.clone();
```

As I found out I cannot obtain microphone stream without user action on page (focus at least). So promise from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` was resolved after I created (cloned) all required stream.

Why when source node is connected to destination node after those clones were created it still influences them and audio is flowing? Is stream somehow connected to node which it was acquired from and this information is persisted when cloning?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Each cloned MediaStream will use the exact same media data as input. The [Media Capture and Streams spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main) defines the algorithm used to [clone a MediaStream](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediastream-clone) which internally relies on the algorithm to [clone a MediaStreamTrack](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#track-clone). The important sentence is "5. Let trackClone's underlying source be the source of track.".